# Support Vectors in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

It might be a very basic question.$\\$
I am considering the SVM optimization problem here.$\\$
In a training set where the data is linearly separable, and we are using a hard margin (no slack allowed), the support vectors lie along the supporting hyperplanes but is the inverse true that all points lying along the supporting hyperplanes are support vectors?

Comment: That's not necessarily the case. You just need enough points to define the hyperplanes.